# Thermostat Wire Terminals

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat

I know wiring a thermostat is red to R white to W green to G yellow to Y and blue to C.  Today I tried to find the answer to a question I thought of.  Red is 24v common is 24v.  Why cant you jump from red to common on thermostat for power for the thermostat?  I couldn't find what would happen and didn't want to test on any products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thermostat power delivered from the furnace nominally 24 VAC. If you shorted out the RED (R) and BLUE (B) connections at the thermostat you would end up shorting the 24 VAC supply in the furnace. This would certainly render your thermostat non-operable and it would could:

1. Blow a fuse in the furnace,
2. Overheat the 24 VAC transformer in the furnace,
3. Render the furnace control functions non-functioning, or
4. Even damage the furnace control board.